# Validation for Translation class I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation Rails

Tags: validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have used gem `i18n-active_record` for translation of data in my website and saving the translations in database. I have given access to edit translations to admin. Everything works fine.

But the wrong part of this update data is admin can update translations without any data(value) which may break the application, so I would wish to put
validations for this class.

If I use like this

```
class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :value, :presence => { :message => "Please enter your value" }
end
```

its not working.

Even I have tried using callbacks and scopes, none of them seems to be working.

Any solution or references please to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting this constraints directly onto the "value" table fields?

This is how it's behaving here:

```
>> class Translation < ActiveRecord::Base
>>   validates :value, :presence => { :message => "Please enter your value" }
>>   end
=> {:presence=>{:message=>"Please enter your value"}}
>> Translation.new.tap { |t| p t.valid?; p t.errors }
false
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fce0f11aa78 @base=#<Translation id: nil, value: nil>, @messages={:value=>["can't be blank", "Please enter your value", "Please enter your value"]}>
=> #<Translation id: nil, value: nil>
>> Translation.new(value: "").tap { |t| p t.valid?; p t.errors }
false
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fce0f0f3798 @base=#<Translation id: nil, value: "">, @messages={:value=>["can't be blank", "Please enter your value", "Please enter your value"]}>
=> #<Translation id: nil, value: "">
>> Translation.new(value: "something").tap { |t| p t.valid?; p t.errors }
true
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fce0f0cb540 @base=#<Translation id: nil, value: "something">, @messages={}>
=> #<Translation id: nil, value: "something">
```

Comment: Hi Frank, 
No it's working.

I have tried the same, but got no luck. The answer works fine if the Class is inherited from activemodel, here its a different case. 

If we use gem "i18n-active_record" the translation class inherits from I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation. 

I have tried in console similarly as your code I am getting the output like this

Translation.new(value: "").tap { |t| p t.valid?; p t.errors }
true

Comment: See the full error report
Translation.new.tap { |t| p t.valid?; p t.errors }
true
<I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation id: nil, value: nil, @messages={}>

Translation.new(value: "").tap { |t| p t.valid?; p t.errors }
true
<I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @messages={}>
Translation.new(value: "something").tap { |t| p t.valid?; p t.errors }
true
<I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation id: nil, value: "something", @messages={}>
<I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation id: nil,value: "something", interpolations: [], is_proc: false>

Comment: FWIW, [`I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation` inherits from `ActiveModel` through `ActiveRecord::Base`](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/active_record/translation.rb#L48).
Can you please paste the result of `I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation.ancestors` ?